# Why do my div's stack on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a mobile site and am having an issue with div's stacking on top of one another. See screenshot.

[image]

You'll see that the "about" content box is opaque, and is covering up the logo and a home button.  That's my header div but unfortunately it's hidden by the content div.  I'm a CSS novice and don't quite have the hang of it yet.  I want the content section to be properly spaced from the header section *(see the actual mobile site, link above)*

Here's the HTML/CSS.

**Header**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    </div><!-- #logo -->

    <div id="home">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png"></a>
    </div><!-- #home -->
</div><!-- #header -->    


#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #444;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#logo {
    padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
    float: left;
}
#home {
    padding: 25px 15px 0 0;
    float: right;
}
```

**Body/content section**

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="content_container">
        <div id="content">
                <h1>about</h1>
                <p>Our goal is to capture your event in the truest way possible, understanding the event, understanding how you want to present the event and then executing the event with the utmost efficiency and effectiveness.</p>
                <p>Our goal is to capture your event in the truest way possible, understanding the event, understanding how you want to present the event and then executing the event with the utmost efficiency and effectiveness.</p>
                <p><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a> today to find out how we can make your next event a success!</p>
        </div><!-- end of #content -->
    </div><!-- end of #content_container -->

    <a href="about.html"><div class="nav"><div class="navText">About</div></div></a>
    <a href="photos.html"><div class="nav"><div class="navText">Photos</div></div></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><div class="nav"><div class="navText">Contact</div></div></a>
    <div id="version">
        <p>Switch Version <br />Mobile | <a href="http://www.studiosimplicit.com/?force-web">Desktop</a></p>
    </div><!-- #version --> 
    <div id="copyright">
        <p>&copy; 2012 Studio Simplicit. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div><!-- end of #copyright -->
</div><!-- #body --> 


    #body {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

    #content_container {
    background: url('../img/content_panel.png') repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

    #content {
    padding: 15px;
}

    #version {
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

    #version a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #version a:hover {
        color: #888;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    background: #333;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 9;
    float: left;
}

    .navText {
    font-family: Avenir, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: How about providing some code or markup so we don't have to fish to help you.

Comment: Reopening in light of newly provided content (code).

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"You'll see that the 'about' content box is opaque"_.  It's not opaque, it's transparent... or more precisely, somewhere in between.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Sorry fellas!  Hopefully the post is more coherent now.  Let me know if anything's still missing.

Comment: @giwook Basically what's happening is that you have `bottom: 0` which will snap the content to the bottom of the page. When you scale the page down, the bottom of the page becomes closer to the header at which point the content will continue upward to cover the header.

Comment: Okay, after some more tinkering I figured out that the absolute positioning was the culprit.  For future reference, how would you keep the absolute positioning AND have div tags that come after it not overlap the original div?

Comment: @giwook In your case you would need to use JavaScript to not let the container pass the bottom of the head. If your primary concern is purely the fact that the content renders on top of the nav, you can just absolute position the navigation and then increase the `z-index` so that it renders on top with the body falling behind it.